# select entries and put in a matrix without loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have the following:

```
   b = [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]
```

whose dimensions are variable.

```
b{1}

ans =

 0     0     0     0
```

I want to put the first entry of each of the 10 vectors as the first column of matrix `A`

2nd column of matrix `A` will be as v the 1st entry of each of the 10 vectors of `r`:

```
r = 

[1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]
```

> > r{1} -->      ans =    10    10    10    10

This is what i need to get:

```
A = 

    v{1}(1)   r{1}(1)
    v{2}(1)   r{2}(1)
    v{3}(1)   r{3}(1)
```

How to do that without a loop is there a way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question but look into the Matlab function, cellfun (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html)

Comment: The title says "select entries and put in a **cell** without loop", but I assume that you want a put the entries in a **matrix**, as you explain so in your question. Should `A` be a **matrix**, not a **cell**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some example data:

```
b = {[ 101:104 ], [ 201:204 ], [ 301:304 ], [ 401:404 ], [ 501:504 ], [ 601:604 ], [ 701:704 ], [ 801:804 ], [ 901:904 ], [ 1001:1004 ]};

r = {[ 2101:2104 ], [ 2201:2204 ], [ 2301:2304 ], [ 2401:2404 ], [ 2501:2504 ], [ 2601:2604 ], [ 2701:2704 ], [ 2801:2804 ], [ 2901:2904 ], [ 3001:3004 ]};
```

Edit: a lot faster solution without looping by using `vertcat`.
Edit: corrected a typo in code.

```
bMatrix = vertcat(b{:});
rMatrix = vertcat(r{:});
A = [ bMatrix(:,1), rMatrix(:,1) ];
```

A lot slower solution by using `cellfun` (`cellfun` does loop) :

```
A = [ cellfun(@(x) x(1), b)', cellfun(@(x) x(1), r)' ];
```

Or in parts:

```
ColumnOneOfMatrixA = cellfun(@(x) x(1), b)';
ColumnTwoOfMatrixA = cellfun(@(x) x(1), r)';
A = [ ColumnOneOfMatrixA, ColumnTwoOfMatrixA ];
```

Both ways give the same result.

```
A =
     101        2101
     201        2201
     301        2301
     401        2401
     501        2501
     601        2601
     701        2701
     801        2801
     901        2901
    1001        3001
```

Answer (score 0):

As Dan notes, `cellfun` is the trick to avoiding this loop.

```
%Setup test data
for ix = 1:10
    b{ix} = ones(1,4)*(ix-1);
    r{ix} = ones(1,4)*(ix+9);
end

%Cellfun based definition of the "A" matrix
A = [...
    cellfun(  @(x)x(1),  b(1:10)  ); ...
    cellfun(  @(x)x(1),  r(1:10)  ); ...
    ]';
```

Here the `cellfun` calls have been set up to return a numeric array containikng the first element of each numeric array in the cell array.  The anonymous function `@(x)x(1)` serves as the core, just returning the first element, and `cellfun` takes care of implementing the appropriate looping without bothering you with the details.

Note that `cellfun` is usually not any faster than the loop that it replaces.  It simply requires less typing, and is arguably easier to read after you learn to work with it.